# What's the difference between saying element1, element2 {display: inline block;} and element1 + element2 (display: inline block;)?

Tags: css, web

What's the difference between

```
 element1, element2 {display: inline block;}
```

and

```
element1 + element2 (display: inline block;)
```

in terms of display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"+"` is the adjacent sibling selector. It will select any element `DIRECTLY AFTER` element (not a child or parent though, a sibling).

Answer (score 3):

element1 , element2: both elements have same class(style), also you can do like this:

```
element1, element2 {display: inline block;}
```

or

```
element1 {display: inline block;}
element2 {display: inline block;}
```

**element1 + element2**: + is for next sibling, all element2 that are placed immediately after element1

Comment: You got the second one wrong, it is not for all element1 after element2, but for all element2 after element1